# Looping a formula in a column while data exists in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck and I'm sure it's simple. I need to run a LOOKUP formula in Column E while data exists in Column A. Column A will have varying amounts of data/rows, it will never be a set number. The problem is that my code wants to loop through ALL of Column E and it takes the macro 20 minutes to run.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub Run_Lookup()
      Range("A1").Select
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         Range("E:E").Formula = "=lookup(A1, G:H)"
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
   End Sub
```

I appreciate any advice.

EDIT: A Visual of my issue...

[image: EDIT: A visual of my issue...]

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can go about this - I tend to dislike DoUntil:

1) Could you simply turn your data into a table? It'll auto-expand column E as needed, no need to be in VBA.

2) Write your loop to first find the end of your data (Hint: Google for LastRow Excel VBA), then loop

```
For I = 1 to LastRow
    'Code here
Next I
```

Comment: Should be For instead of From, I believe

Comment: Well, that's what I get for coding first thing in the morning

Comment: I'll look into this, but I'm struggling. I also struggle to find the flaw in my code. Run the formula until A=null. Should be simple and I feel like I'm missing something simple. The logic flow seems easy. Thank you for your reply. *Edit* AM I missing something with the very easy excel formula???

Comment: I mean, your formula is bad in and of itself - it won't work as per https://support.office.com/en-us/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb . Try vlookup instead, you might have better results

Comment: Well, my formula and VLOOKUP both work. Literally the only issue is that it's looping through Column E in it's entirety, not Column A. I interrupt the macro using CTRL Break, and the data I need is there....it just needs to stop when column A is empty. It is not stopping at the last entry in Column A.